# how to autostart redis-server in ubuntu 20 desktop

Tags: ubuntu, redis-server

I'm currently running Redis-server in my local development environment Ubuntu 20.04. Every time I open my desktop computer I always use this `Redis-server --daemonize yes` to start the Redis server. Is there a way to make it autostart when the desktop computer turned on?

Answer (score 28):

If your system is using `systemd`, the way to launch it at start-up is:

```
sudo systemctl enable redis-server
```

Comment: Not working:
`Failed to enable unit: Unit file redis-server.service does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about redis, I thought it already gets installed as a service. In general you can use systemd. Something like the following:

```sh
cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/redis.service
[Unit]
Description=Start Redis Application
After=syslog.target
After=network.target[Service]
User=root
Type=simple

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/root/
ExecStart=Redis-server --daemonize yes
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=redis

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using official redis documentation https://redis.io/topics/quickstart by Installing Redis more properly.

Here are the steps:

The following instructions can be used to perform a proper installation using the init script shipped with Redis 2.4 in a Debian or Ubuntu-based distribution.

Let's assume you already copied redis-server and redis-cli executables under /usr/local/bin.

**1. Create a directory in which to store your Redis config files and your data:**

- sudo mkdir /etc/redis
- sudo mkdir /var/redis

**2. Copy the init script that you'll find in the Redis distribution under the utils directory into /etc/init.d. We suggest calling it with the name of the port where you are running this instance of Redis. For example:**

- sudo cp utils/redis_init_script /etc/init.d/redis_6379

**3. Edit the init script.**

- sudo vi /etc/init.d/redis_6379

*Make sure to modify REDISPORT accordingly to the port you are using. Both the pid file path and the configuration file name depend on the port number.*

**4. Copy the template configuration file you'll find in the root directory of the Redis distribution into /etc/redis/ using the port number as name, for instance:**

- sudo cp redis.conf /etc/redis/6379.conf

**5. Create a directory inside /var/redis that will work as data and working directory for this Redis instance:**

- sudo mkdir /var/redis/6379

**6. Edit the configuration file, making sure to perform the following changes:**

- Set daemonize to yes (by default it is set to no).
- Set the pidfile to /var/run/redis_6379.pid (modify the port if needed).
- Change the port accordingly. In our example it is not needed as the default port is already 6379.
- Set your preferred loglevel.
- Set the logfile to /var/log/redis_6379.log
- Set the dir to /var/redis/6379 (very important step!)

**7. Finally add the new Redis init script to all the default runlevels using the following command:**

- sudo update-rc.d redis_6379 defaults

**8. You are done! Now you can try running your instance with:**

- sudo /etc/init.d/redis_6379 start

***Make sure that everything is working as expected:***

- *Try pinging your instance with **redis-cli**.*
- *Do a test save with **redis-cli save** and check that the dump file is - correctly stored into /var/redis/6379/ (you should find a file called dump.rdb).*
- *Check that your Redis instance is correctly logging in the log file.*
- *If it's a new machine where you can try it without problems make sure that after a reboot everything is still working.*